# What is Spider-man's support for his webs here?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Every time I watch *Avengers: Infinity War*, I can't figure out how Spider-man is able to swing in an open area. Is it a mistake in the movie?
Please watch the Ebony-Cull invasion scene following:

Let me support this using pics:

[image]

Here, he uses SOME support after jumping ahead of the bridge, note that the nearest trees/buildings are quite away and he is swinging away from the bridge, so the web is not on the bridge railing.

[image]

Here the web support's height is far more than any tree possible in the surroundings, the web seems to have no logical support.

[image]
[image]

Notice there are trees in the corners of the road only, too small trees compared to the very long length of the web(s).

I see  that his webs have no logical support whatsoever.

Answer (score 14):

In most cases..

## Off-screen tall buildings

Or buildings on-screen that we would consider "out of range"...

Spider-man's webshooters apparently have **incredibly range** and he can hit tall buildings from a considerable distance to form "anchor" points for his swinging webs.

Recall also that Spider-man is **incredibly** strong and can make much more use of what would seem to be only a short amount of web to get a flying start.

Unfortunately. the webs themselves don't lend themselves to showing up easily in a movie such as this given their thin nature and the speed of the action.

In addition, in some of those shots, particularly when swinging away from the bridge... **he's not attached.** He's in mid-air.

He's using the momentum from the previous "swing" to leap *towards* his next target and will re-connect as he descends on his trajectory.